# How can I create fixed-width paragraphs with PDFbox?

Tags: html, pdfbox, paragraph

I can insert simple text like this:

```
document = new PDDocument();
page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
content.beginText();
content.moveTextPositionByAmount (10 , 10);
content.drawString ("test text");
content.endText();
content.close();
```

but how can I create a paragraph similar to HTML using the width attribute?

```
<p style="width:200px;">test text</p>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **Warning**: this answer applies to and old version of PDFBox and relies on features that has since been deprecated. See the comments below for more details.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598157/520779) it's not possible to insert line breaks into some text and have PDF display it correctly (whether using PDFBox or something else), so I believe auto-wrapping some text to fit in some width may also be something it can't do automatically. (besides, there are many ways to wrap a text - whole words only, break them in smaller parts, etc)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6531362/520779) to another question (about centering a string) gives some pointers on how to do this yourself. Assuming you wrote a function `possibleWrapPoints(String):int[]` to list all points in the text a word wrap can happen (excluding "zero", including "text length"), one possible solution could be:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD; // Or whatever font you want.
int fontSize = 16; // Or whatever font size you want.
int paragraphWidth = 200;
String text = "test text";

int start = 0;
int end = 0;
int height = 10;
for ( int i : possibleWrapPoints(text) ) {
    float width = font.getStringWidth(text.substring(start,i)) / 1000 * fontSize;
    if ( start < end && width > paragraphWidth ) {
        // Draw partial text and increase height
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(10 , height);
        content.drawString(text.substring(start,end));
        height += font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;
        start = end;
    }
    end = i;
}
// Last piece of text
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(10 , height);
content.drawString(text.substring(start));
```

One example of `possibleWrapPoints`, that allow wrapping at any point that's not part of a word ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/520779)), could be:

```
int[] possibleWrapPoints(String text) {
    String[] split = text.split("(?<=\\W)");
    int[] ret = new int[split.length];
    ret[0] = split[0].length();
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < split.length ; i++ )
        ret[i] = ret[i-1] + split[i].length();
    return ret;
}
```

**Update:** some additional info:

- The PDF file format was designed to look the same in different situations, functionality like the one you requested makes sense in a PDF editor/creator, but not in the PDF file *per se*. For this reason, most "low level" tools tend to concentrate on dealing with the file format itself and leave away stuff like that.
- Higher level tools OTOH usually have means to make this conversion. An example is [Platypus](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/platypus.html#) (for Python, though), that **do** have easy ways of creating paragraphs, and relies on the lower level [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/) functions to do the actual PDF rendering. I'm unaware of similar tools for PDFBox, but [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisf/entry/converting_html_to_pdf_using) gives some hints on how to convert HTML content to PDF in a Java environment, using freely available tools. Haven't tried them myself, but I'm posting here since it might be useful (in case my hand-made attempt above is not enough).

Comment: In PDF it is possible to make a line break. (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15205956/1016477))

Comment: Just for reference: This answer uses the API that was current at that time and is now deprecated. Text can now be added by [`showText`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html#showText(java.lang.String)) and line breaks added directly directly by [`newLine`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageContentStream.html#newLine()) .

Comment: This is a quite old post and a lot has changed with PDFBox. Also have a look at [PDFBox-Layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout) which makes it way easier to handle all these concerns - wrapping texts, diff layouts etc.

Answer (score 7):

I have been working combining Lukas answer with mgibsonbr and arrived at this. More helpful to people looking for an out-of-the-box solution, I think.

```
private void write(Paragraph paragraph) throws IOException {
    out.beginText();
    out.appendRawCommands(paragraph.getFontHeight() + " TL\n");
    out.setFont(paragraph.getFont(), paragraph.getFontSize());
    out.moveTextPositionByAmount(paragraph.getX(), paragraph.getY());
    out.setStrokingColor(paragraph.getColor());

    List<String> lines = paragraph.getLines();
    for (Iterator<String> i = lines.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        out.drawString(i.next().trim());
        if (i.hasNext()) {
            out.appendRawCommands("T*\n");
        }
    }
    out.endText();

}

public class Paragraph {

    /** position X */
    private float x;

    /** position Y */
    private float y;

    /** width of this paragraph */
    private int width = 500;

    /** text to write */
    private String text;

    /** font to use */
    private PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    /** font size to use */
    private int fontSize = 10;

    private int color = 0;

    public Paragraph(float x, float y, String text) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.text = text;
    }

    /**
     * Break the text in lines
     * @return
     */
    public List<String> getLines() throws IOException {
        List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();

        String[] split = text.split("(?<=\\W)");
        int[] possibleWrapPoints = new int[split.length];
        possibleWrapPoints[0] = split[0].length();
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < split.length ; i++ ) {
            possibleWrapPoints[i] = possibleWrapPoints[i-1] + split[i].length();
        }

        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for ( int i : possibleWrapPoints ) {
            float width = font.getStringWidth(text.substring(start,i)) / 1000 * fontSize;
            if ( start < end && width > this.width ) {
                result.add(text.substring(start,end));
                start = end;
            }
            end = i;
        }
        // Last piece of text
        result.add(text.substring(start));
        return result;
    }

    public float getFontHeight() {
        return font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;
    }

    public Paragraph withWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public Paragraph withFont(PDType1Font font, int fontSize) {
        this.font = font;
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
        return this;
    }

    public Paragraph withColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public PDType1Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

    public int getFontSize() {
        return fontSize;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class PdfParagraph2 {

    public enum Alignment {
        LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create a PDF document, add pages, and obtain content stream
        // (You should have your PDFBox setup code here)
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        // Create a content stream for the page
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        float startX = 1; // Left margin
        float startY = 740; // Top margin
        float lineSpacing = 12; // Line spacing
        int maxWidth = 600; // Maximum line width
        Alignment alignment = Alignment.RIGHT; // Set alignment

        // Sample text for the paragraph
        String text = "This is a sample paragraph." +
                      "Itmayspanmultiplelinesdependingonthewidthofthecontent. Paragraph 1: This is the first paragraph.af aFA FF AF AFAF Af af aF Af aF Af aF Af aF Af fafasfafas af f af af af af fffffffffffffs sgs ";

        float[] nextPosition = addLine(contentStream, "Imli chor", startX, startY, lineSpacing, maxWidth, Alignment.LEFT);
        addLine(contentStream, "Chor", nextPosition[0], nextPosition[1], lineSpacing, maxWidth, Alignment.LEFT);
        contentStream.close();
        document.save("D:\\pdf\\output1.pdf");
        document.close();
        // Continue adding more content or save the document
        // (You should have the rest of your PDF generation code here)
    }
    public static float[] addLine(PDPageContentStream contentStream, String text, float startX, float startY, float lineSpacing, int maxWidth, Alignment alignment) throws IOException {
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);

        String[] lines = text.split("\n");
        float yOffset = startY;
        float maxLineWidth = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            float xOffset;
            float lineWidth = getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, line);

            // Calculate the X-coordinate based on the alignment
            switch (alignment) {
                case LEFT:
                    xOffset = startX;
                    break;
                case CENTER:
                    xOffset = startX + (maxWidth - Math.min(maxWidth, lineWidth)) / 2;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    xOffset = startX + maxWidth - Math.min(maxWidth, lineWidth);
                    break;
                default:
                    xOffset = startX; // Default to left alignment
            }

            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            StringBuilder lineText = new StringBuilder();
            float currentLineWidth = 0;

            for (String word : words) {
                float wordWidth = getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, word);

                if (currentLineWidth + wordWidth > maxWidth) {
                    // The word exceeds the remaining line width, start a new line
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(Math.max(xOffset, startX), yOffset);
                    contentStream.showText(lineText.toString());
                    contentStream.endText();

                    // Move to the next line
                    yOffset -= lineSpacing;
                    lineText.setLength(0); // Clear the lineText
                    currentLineWidth = 0;
                }

                if (lineText.length() > 0) {
                    lineText.append(" "); // Add space between words
                    currentLineWidth += getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, " "); // Update line width
                }

                lineText.append(word);
                currentLineWidth += wordWidth;
                maxLineWidth = Math.max(currentLineWidth, maxLineWidth);
            }

            // Add the last line in the paragraph
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(Math.max(xOffset, startX), yOffset);
            contentStream.showText(lineText.toString());
            contentStream.endText();

            // Move to the next line
            //yOffset -= lineSpacing;
        }

        // Return the next X and Y positions
        return new float[]{startX+maxLineWidth+getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, " "), yOffset};
    }
    
    public static float[] addParagraph(PDPageContentStream contentStream, String text, float startX, float startY, float lineSpacing, int maxWidth, Alignment alignment) throws IOException {
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);

        String[] lines = text.split("\n");
        float yOffset = startY;

        for (String line : lines) {
            float xOffset;
            float lineWidth = getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, line);

            // Calculate the X-coordinate based on the alignment
            switch (alignment) {
                case LEFT:
                    xOffset = startX;
                    break;
                case CENTER:
                    xOffset = startX + (maxWidth - Math.min(maxWidth, lineWidth)) / 2;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    xOffset = startX + maxWidth - Math.min(maxWidth, lineWidth);
                    break;
                default:
                    xOffset = startX; // Default to left alignment
            }

            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            StringBuilder lineText = new StringBuilder();
            float currentLineWidth = 0;

            for (String word : words) {
                float wordWidth = getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, word);

                if (currentLineWidth + wordWidth > maxWidth) {
                    // The word exceeds the remaining line width, start a new line
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(Math.max(xOffset, startX), yOffset);
                    contentStream.showText(lineText.toString());
                    contentStream.endText();

                    // Move to the next line
                    yOffset -= lineSpacing;
                    lineText.setLength(0); // Clear the lineText
                    currentLineWidth = 0;
                }

                if (lineText.length() > 0) {
                    lineText.append(" "); // Add space between words
                    currentLineWidth += getStringWidth(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12, " "); // Update line width
                }

                lineText.append(word);
                currentLineWidth += wordWidth;
            }

            // Add the last line in the paragraph
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(Math.max(xOffset, startX), yOffset);
            contentStream.showText(lineText.toString());
            contentStream.endText();

            // Move to the next line
            yOffset -= lineSpacing;
        }

        // Return the next X and Y positions
        return new float[]{startX, yOffset};
    }

    private static float getStringWidth(PDType1Font font, float fontSize, String text) throws IOException {
        return font.getStringWidth(text) * fontSize / 1000f;
    }
}
```