# Calculation String-Width in PDFbox seems only to count characters?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've the following issue. I try to calculate the width of a string in PDFbox to center it in a rectangle. Now my problem is, that I get the same width for 12 as for 32, but the 1 is smaller than the 3 so that my text is for 12 not centered. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Has nobody an idea to solve my question?

Answer (score 34):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640152/how-can-i-create-fix-width-paragraph-with-pdfbox):

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD; // Or whatever font you want.
int fontSize = 16; // Or whatever font size you want.
float width = font.getStringWidth(text.substring(start,i)) / 1000 * fontSize;
```

Comment: I've been looking for some conversion formula from the units I get from PDFontDescriptor to PTs and this worked like a charm! I would love to know where the magic 1000 comes from and if possible, the whole logic behind the formula on the last line.

Comment: According to [getStringWidth()](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getStringWidth(java.lang.String)) documentation, the width of the string is expressed in 1/1000 units of text space. Multiplying it gets us back up to points.

Answer (score -1):

In some fonts the numbers do all have the same width. Just try it for different fonts in MSWord for example. So the fact that you get the same width for 12 and 32 could be correct.

Comment: Considering the question is from 2012, asking the OP to "try" something appears very naive; do you really think the OP is still working on that 5 years old issue?

Comment: I don't do age discrimination. All questions are equal. You think some questions are more equal than others?

Comment: Of course one can answer old questions, and one can even give good answers which are well received by other people, maybe even eventually accepted. What I consider naive, though, is thinking the OP is still acutely interested in that very problem, let alone working on it. Only then, though, the OP would be likely to try something in respect to the issue. Thus, asking him to try something to me appears naive. Furthermore, the question of the OP contains to little detail to say whether the issue is caused by the font or by the OP's code; if he was interested, he would have added some code etc..