# What is the PDFBox equivalent to iText document.add(new Paragraph(string))

Tags: pdfbox

I'm finally dumping iText for PDFBox. The requirements for the document to be created are trivial. With iText I've been using something like

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
  document.add(new Paragraph(foo.getName()));
}
```

What is the PDFBox equivalent to that? [Their Hello World example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/HelloWorld.java?view=markup) doesn't really give a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFBox doesn't have a high level API for generating blocks of text (yet). There are some articles such as
[How can I create fixed-width paragraphs with PDFbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640152/how-can-i-create-fixed-width-paragraphs-with-pdfbox)
[How to generate multiple lines in PDF using Apache pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635275/how-to-generate-multiple-lines-in-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox/19683618#19683618)

In addition there are projects such as https://github.com/dhorions/boxable who add table formatting to PDFBox.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of all of them before I placed my question (SO suggests them). However, since those answers go a few years back I thought things might have changed for the better in the meantime. Sigh...

Comment: @MarcelStör Adding layout'ing capabilities has been discussed by PDFBox committers, e.g. [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2618) on their Jira; unfortunately the opinion prevails that any less-than-perfect layouter is even less desirable than no layouter at all.